# Auto mount ext4 usb so that all users can write to it

Tags: mount, permissions

I have a usb device ext4 file system, 
I manually mount it like this

```
  mount -t ext4 /dev/sda1  /mnt/sdcard1
```

then change permissions manually to enable others to write to it.

What line should I use in fstab so that all users have read/write permissions on it..

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/174776/modify-fstab-entry-so-all-users-can-read-and-write-to-an-ext4-volume

Answer (score 0):

Since you are referring to `fstab`, I assume that this device will always be connected to your system.

Try the following:

```
mkdir -p /mnt/sdcard1
chmod 777 /mnt/sdcard1
```

and add the following line at the end of your `/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/sda1    /mnt/sdcard1    ext4    rw,user,exec,umask=000 0 0
```

Note:
If the device is not presenting during the boot time, boot might take long time before it fails to mount the device. make sure that the device is always connected and the name is correct.